# File.Separator in Properties

Tags: java, properties

I am using **java.util.Properties**. However, it cannot read **File.separator** inside the config file.

As an example, I add this line to the config file. **source.dir = D:/workspace/Temp1\Temp2** (Note that File.separator is used to separate Temp1 and Temp2)

The below line is used to load propertis:

```
 Properties properties = new Properties ();
 properties.load(new FileInputStream("configFileAddress"));
```

The result is: **source.dir = D:/workspace/Temp1Temp2** (File.Separator is removed).

Any one knows, how can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you using a mixture of forward and back slashes in your file path?

Comment: Escape the ``\`` with another ``\``.

Comment: The first part is loaded from a file (and it is assume it is correct for different os). The second part is created by my program and I used File.Separator to work with different OS.

Comment: I used two File.Separator (\\\), but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
 source.dir = D:/workspace/Temp1\Temp2
```

To:

```
source.dir = D:\\workspace\\Temp1\\Temp2
```

> This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value
>   of the system property file.separator.  On UNIX systems the value of
>   this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.